# react-native iOS App receives firebase dynamic links when run in debug scheme but not when run in release scheme

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

I have integrated the dynamic links sdk using react-native firebase. I tested the deep links by opening the url by tapping on them in a text message which lead to a screen displaying my apps name and the information along with the open button. Tapping the open button took me to the app store's page for my application. I then installed the app using xcode in a debug scheme. The dynamic link was received correctly and everything worked fine. I then did the same process but changed the scheme to release. This time the url received was unfortunately null. I have debugged the native code as well and can see that `dynamicLinkFromCustomSchemeURL:url` contains the correct deep link in debug scheme but not in release scheme.